# Solr V6.2: Facet Query on numbers

Tags: solr, lucene, facet

I have to perform facet range query on numbers where I don't have the upper limit Ranges are as follows:

Range: 1 to *, 3 to *, 5 to * and so on.

facet.range requires `start`,`end` and `gap` . How to achieve the faceting on above range. `end` doesn't takes * from numeric values. Facet count for all the ranges have to achieved in single query.

I am using solrj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this after some r&d, solr has a clause for providing custom intervals. This can be achieved through it.